# Lenovo IdeaPad y510p, MATSHITA DVD-RAM results CRC error while coping 7GB file from Double Layer DVD

Tags: drivers, dvd, file-transfer, lenovo-laptop, crc

I Have Ideapad y510p with MATSHITA DVD-RAM UJ8DB. While I tring to copy 7GB file do HDD almost in the middle (after 42%) it stucks and after a while it prompt that file can't be copied due to error.

In fact I tring to install a game so when it does the same thing during the installation process, it prompt that there is some CRC error.

I know that DVD from the game is recorded with Double Layer and it requires DVD 9. But I have Double Layer DVD reader.

I have 2 OS on my computer - so I tried it in Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 13.10. I tried also to reinstall DVD driver in Windows but without any effect. DVD from the game isn't broken because when I try to install it in the different computer it copied all the files without any error.

Does anyone knows what is wrong here? Is it possible that DVD reader could be damaged?

I will be very appreciate for any help.

Comment: If a different optical drive is reading the disc fine, then either the reader that doesn't read the drive is malfunctioning, or it may have tighter tolerances than the drive that can read the disk (meaning while one can handle a small scrath, the other might not).

Comment: But it seems that the driver is stuck when it's trying to switch between layers, so it may indicate that the drive is malfunctioning

Comment: I mentioned it could be either drive failure (malfunctioning) or tighter tolerances.  If you really think it's drive failure, you could try another dual layer disc and see if you have issues.  Personally I think it's a big leap to assume that 42% is the point where the layers switch . . . I would imagine the threshold to be closer to 67% (4.7 GB / 7GB) if that's the only file on the disk.  If there is other content on there, who knows where the flip between layers is . . .